# The number of simple graphs with vertex set size $n$ is $2^{{}^n\mathrm C_2}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Why is it $2^{{}^n\mathrm C_2}$? How do you derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $C_2^n$ edges, since the edges can be mapped bijectively to unordered pairs of distinct vertices (the two elements of the pair are the edge's endpoints).

Each edge can be connected or unconnected, so in total there are $2^{C_2^n}$ choices.

Comment: ahh.. "mapped bijectively to unordered pairs.." thank you!

Comment: @TheLastCipher Do you have trouble understanding that phrase?

Comment: No.. That phrase made it clear to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $V=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  The complete graph $K_n$ on vertex set $V$ has ${n \choose 2}$ edges; denoted its edge set by $E(K_n)$.  Every simple graph $G=(V,E')$ on vertex set $V$ is represented by a unique subset $E' \subseteq E(K_n)$, and conversely, every subset of $E(K_n)$ gives a  unique simple graph on $V$.  Hence, there is a bijective correspondence between simple graphs on $V$ and subsets of $E(K_n)$.  The number of subsets of $E(K_n)$ is $2^{|E(K_n)|} = 2^{{n \choose 2}}$.